# Why isn't jQuery changes to colspan ot showing in html src?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a jQuery method that modifies a colspan attribute based on a users role. When I am all other roles the function and jQuery method works perfectly however as a viewer role the jQuery say it makes the change, a onclick method in the td element of the modified colspan says it changed but the html src is not changing and displaying according to the original value.

The Java function

```
    function changeFooterLength(action,tableType,role)
    {
    if(role != "viewer"){
    if(action == "show"){
        $("#footer_filler").attr("colspan",13);
    }else if(action == "hide"){
        if(tableType != "Search"){
            $("#footer_filler").attr("colspan",10);
        }else{
            $("#footer_filler").attr("colspan",10);
        }
    }
    }else{
    if(action == "show"){
        $("#footer_filler").attr("colspan",12);
    }else if(action == "hide"){
        alert($('#footer_filler').attr('colspan'));
        $("#footer_filler").attr("colspan",9);
        alert($('#footer_filler').attr('colspan'));
    }
    }
    }
```

The td element:

```
    <td id="footer_filler" colspan="12" class="table_footer_excel" align="left" onclick="alert($('#footer_filler').attr('colspan'));">
        <a href="<c:url value='/export'/>">
     <img src="<c:url value="/resources/images/icon_microsoftexcel.png"/>" style="width: 20px; height: 20px; margin-left: 5px; border: none;" />
    </a>
     </td>
```

From my eyes, the logic seems solid but it isn't working can anyone help me understand why?

Comment: HTML source is what returns server, why should it change according to client side script?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the DOM inspector in your browser's developer tools. The source is the 'original' from the server source and will not undergo any changes when the DOM is modified by JavaScript / jQuery.

Comment: It is designed to run in IE 6-8, but i ran it in Firefox DOM inspector and walked through the code.I saw that the colspan attribute is being updated and modified correctly but it is not being displayed/shown correctly. Which is weird as with other situations that this code works for it functions just fine, just not this situation.

Comment: So is your question different than what you originally posted?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. The trouble, I believe, was caused by not declaring a doc type for the browser to interpret. 

But I ultimately went another direction by specifically creating the table footer cells for each situation, and adding a border to the overall table. It is currently an acceptable fix. Thanks everyone for your help.